# sscanf: get first and last token in a string

Tags: c, scanf

Is it possible by using sscanf to get the first token then skip some tokens and then get the last one?

For example, the output of /bin/ps -fu1000

```
  cm  2249  1548   0   0:00.00 ttys001    0:00.01 man sscanf
```

I have tried:

```
sscanf(line, "%s %[^\n]", user, cmd);
```

The result should be:

```
user = "cm";
cmd = "man sscanf":
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it's ugly and can't be error checked properly.

```
/* assuming `user` and `cmd` are character arrays defined with 42 bytes */
if (sscanf(line, "%41s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s %41[^\n]", user, cmd) != 2) {
    /* handle error */
} else {
    /* hopefully ok */
}
```

You can replace some of the `%*s` with `%*d`. The `*` means that the item is parsed but not assigned anywhere (it is ignored).

In the statement, there are 6 ignored items corresponding to the items between `"cm"` and `"man sscanf"` in your example.

Also note I limited the input to 41 characters in the scanf itself. Make sure you do not write outside the objects.

---

EDIT: I added a space before the last conversion because, unlike `%s` or `%d` conversions, the `%[` conversion does not skip leading whitespace.

Comment: Right, ugly as hell!
Have you any other idea?

Comment: What's not error checked about it?  You check that there are 6 fields between the user and the command; since you don't care what's in them, the `%*s` format is OK.  I would probably put spaces between the `%*s` formats for easier readability, but what you've got there is fine.  If you want to check that the numeric fields are numbers, and the time field is formatted as a time, you can add to the format string.  But your answer looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'd better look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)