# sscanf to get segment of string surrounded by two fixed strings

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to remove the extension of a file (I know it is `.txt`) using `sscanf()`. I've tried with many format strings I think may work, but with no success. The main problem is that I just can't understand `sscanf()`'s documentation, so I don't get how to use this `[=%[*][width][modifiers]type=]` I've tried to tell it that end must be ".txt" or to save initial string in a variable and a `%4c`corresponding to the extension in another one, but again… can't make it work.

I know this has been asked before here: [sscanf: get first and last token in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510858/sscanf-get-first-and-last-token-in-a-string) but as I said... I don´t understand its solution.

The part of my code that does that:

```
sscanf(fileName,"the_sender_is_%s%*[.txt]", sender);
```

The input file name is, for example: "the_sender_is_Monika.txt"

In `sender` I should have

```
Monika
```

but whatever I try gives me

```
Monika.txt
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Perhaps you could post some code to explain what you are trying to do and where you think the problem is.

Comment: I need to save the file's name (without extension). I must use sscanf, thats it

Comment: What you are asking is not clear since `sscanf` is used to read data from a string. It's unrelated to saving a file's name.

Comment: the string is the file's name

Comment: You can also use `strstr( fileName, ".txt" )` to determine the location of `.txt` in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
sscanf(fileName,"the_sender_is_%s%*[.txt]", sender);
```

The function reads as much as it can with `%s` before it processes `%*[.txt]`.

Use

```
sscanf(fileName,"the_sender_is_%[^.]", sender);
```

Comment: From  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf: `[^characters] Negated scanset Any number of characters none of them specified as characters between the brackets.`

Answer (score 2):

While `sscanf()` is powerful, it is not the universal tool.  There are limits on what you can do with it, and you're hitting them.  A moderate approximation to the task would be:

```
char body[32];
char tail[5];
if (sscanf("longish-name-without-dots.txt", "%31[^.]%4s", body, tail) != 2)
    …oops — can't happen with the constant string, but maybe with a variable one…
```

This gets you `longish-name-without-dots` into `body` and `.txt` into `tail`. But it won't work all that well if there are dots in the name part before the extension.

You're probably looking for:

```
const char *file = "longish-name.with.dots-before.txt";
char *dot = strrchr(file, '.');
if (dot == NULL)
    …oops — can't happen with the literal, but maybe with a variable…
strcpy(tail, dot);  // Beware buffer overflow
memcpy(body, file, dot - file);
body[dot - file] = '\0';
```